# Deploy contract with truffle, how to call in Nethereum?

Tags: truffle, addresses, events, nethereum

I am currently deploying my ChangeManager contract in truffle and I want to call the contract later in Nethereum.
For this I need the contract address in Nethereum. I figured I could just create an event which is emitted in the constructor like so `emit ChangeManagerEvent(address)`. 
Currently I am testing this in a truffle testsuite but I can't seem to filter for the events triggered in the constructor of my ChangeManager contract.
How can I subscribe to events which have been emitted by the constructor in truffle?

```
contract('ChangeManager', function (accounts) {
it('should have emitted event with contract address', async function () {
    changemanager = await  ChangeManager.deployed();
    var event = changemanager.allEvents();

    event.watch(function (error, result) {
        if (!error)
            console.log("Result: ", result.event);
    });
});
```

The goal of this undertaking is to call the contract in Nethereum after I have received the constructor event there. Maybe you have a better suggestion how I could access a contract deployed by truffle in Nethereum.

Answer (score 1):

I have found out how to get the event in the truffle test suite:

```
var event = changemanager.allEvents({fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'});
```

It seems not to default to this option.
Would be still happy to get suggestions on how to pass contract addresses from truffle to Nethereum.